# custom control to select coordinates on a picturebox or panel?

Tags: controls, mouse, picturebox

I'm working on an application to display DICOM Files and now I'm getting into MPR. Is there a control that will allow you to have like a line in a picturebox or panel like this:

http://www.vcreatelogic.com/docs/gcf-2.6.0/html/MPRView.jpg
The intention is to move that line and perform some stuff while is moving, so I basically need some sort of control or custom control (or maybe a custom icon) that will allow the user to see where he's moving in the picturebox as he moves the mouse.

Thank you!

UPDATE:
Here's the code I'm using:

In the Mouse Down of the Picturebox:

```
 if (e.Clicks == 2)
        {

            horizontalstart = new Point(0, e.Y);//Start point of Horizontal line.
            horizontalend = new Point(picbox_mpr.Width, e.Y);//End point of Horizontal line.
            verticalstart = new Point(e.X, 0);//Start point of Vertical line
            verticalend = new Point(e.X, picbox_mpr.Height);//End point of Vertical line.
 }
```

Then in the MouseMove (where I can Pan the picture) I want those lines to remain fixed in the spot that were drawn..

UPDATE:
The whole idea is to draw the lines if the user double click in the image, then if the image is moved, move those lines along with the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first,the method I am giving does not require a custom control in order to work,it makes use of two of the events provided by PictureBox to run the logic,but if still you need a custom control you should be able to do that by porting these methods to that control with a little coding.

The following are two fields that will hold most of the values in our logic,

```
private Point horizontalstart, horizontalend;
private Point verticalstart, verticalend;
private bool drawlines;//Specifies a value whether PictureBox should redraw itself.
```

Let me explain what are these points for;
The first Point statement holds starting and end point of Horizontal line,and
the second Point statement holds starting and end point of Vertical line.
When you'r done with it write this code in `MouseMoveEvent` of your `PictureBox`;

```
    private void SourcePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(drawlines==true)//If the lines should move.
        {
         horizontalstart = new Point(0, e.Y);//Start point of Horizontal line.
         horizontalend = new Point(SourcePictureBox.Width, e.Y);//End point of Horizontal line.
         verticalstart = new Point(e.X, 0);//Start point of Vertical line
         verticalend = new Point(e.X, SourcePictureBox.Height);//End point of Vertical line.
         SourcePictureBox.Invalidate();//Force PictureBox to repaint.
        }

        else if(drawlines==false)//To lock the lines at current coordinates.
        {
         //Add any code if needed.
        }
    }
```

where `SourcePictureBox` is the PictureBox that we are operating upon.As soon as the `MouseMoveEvent` is raised new coordinates for both lines are calculated and a repaint message is sent to PictureBox,which draws the lines using the coordinates declared and calculated above.

Ok so now write the code below in the `Paint` event of your PictureBox;

```
    private void SourcePictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SourcePictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.WindowText, horizontalstart, horizontalend);//Draw Horizontal line.
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.WindowText, verticalstart, verticalend);//Draw Vertical line.
        }
    }
```

One more thing that i noticed in your image,the guidelines the image is showing are a little small than the image,if this is the case,then replace both the statements in `MouseMoveEvent` event excluding the `Invalidate()` one with the following;

```
        horizontalstart = new Point(0+10, e.Y);//Start point of Horizontal line.

        horizontalend = new Point(SourcePictureBox.Width-10, e.Y);//End point of Horizontal line.

        verticalstart = new Point(e.X, 0+10);//Start point of Vertical line

        verticalend = new Point(e.X, SourcePictureBox.Height-10);//End point of Vertical line.
```

But what's new in these statements,nothing except they increase the start point of both lines by value 10(int) and decrease the end points with value 10,thus giving you some space between the edges of PictureBox and the guiding lines.Please note if you want to increase or decrease the space replace value 10 with a value you would like but keep in mind the value must not be bigger than half of the size of your PictureBox.
The other thing i would like to address is if you want to `change the colour of guiding lines`,replace the first argument of both statements in `Paint Event` with any of values offered by class [SystemPens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systempens.aspx).If there is nothing in the class that satisfies you,you are always free to create on for yourself.If you know how to do it,then its the best choice,incase if you need some help,take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983677%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).Creating a new pen gives you the option of defining a width for the guilding lines.

**Update**

`At anytime,to stop the lines from moving,set **drawlines**(declared above) to **false**,to resume their functionality set it to **true**.

It's not a foolproof method but I Hope it's enough to get your job done,and don't forget to rename the PictureBox and associated events with the name of your PictureBox.

Comment: @Matimont I've tried something,hope it helps you achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm! Now, here's another thing, I have a Mousemove event that repaints the picture in the paint event. How can I keep the drawn line fixed? every time I move the mouse it moves, and i'd like it fixed

Comment: @Matimont Do you want the guiding lines to be fixed all the time,I mean,do the lines need to look like a big plus sign which doesn't move.

Comment: Right, When the user double clicks the picture, then the lines are drawn using the code you provided. Then, if the user pans the picture (there's a function where you can pan the picture), I want the lines to remain fixed in the spot the user clicked the first time

Comment: @Matimont Could you please explain the thing you asked in the last comment with some images and a little more brief explanation ?

Comment: I added some code, that's in the mouse down event. What I'd like is to keep those lines fixed in the spot were drawn during the mouse move event..

Comment: @Matimont I've updated the code see if this is what you asked for.If not please inform me.I'll be glad to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, my implementation is: the user double clicks anywhere in the image, then the lines are drawn. If the user pans the picture, the the lines should move along with the picture and remain in the same spot all the time. See my code in the answer I published, is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

here's the code:

```
//Variable declaration:
    private Point horizontalstart, horizontalend, verticalstart, verticalend, horizontalstart_initialpoint, horizontalend_initialpoint, verticalstart_initialpoint, verticalend_initialpoint;
    System.Drawing.Pen redline= new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    private Point redlinemovedpoints = Point.Empty;
    private Point redline_panstart = Point.Empty;


 void picbox_mpr_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        redline_panstart = new Point(e.X, e.Y); //saves the point from where you pan the picture

 if (e.Clicks == 2) //if the user double clicks, then the red line is drawn in the PictureBox
        {
            horizontalstart = new Point(0, e.Y);//Start point of Horizontal line.
            horizontalend = new Point(picbox_mpr.Width, e.Y);//End point of Horizontal line.
            verticalstart = new Point(e.X, 0);//Start point of Vertical line
            verticalend = new Point(e.X, picbox_mpr.Height);//End point of Vertical line.

            //fixed reference points, this is used to store where the line was drawn initially.
            horizontalstart_initialpoint= horizontalstart;
            horizontalend_initialpoint = horizontalend;
            verticalstart_initialpoint = verticalstart;
            verticalend_initialpoint = verticalend;

            picbox_mpr.Invalidate(); // Draw the lines (see paint event at the bottom)
        }


 void picbox_mpr_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

 if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left & pan) // don't worry about pan, is a variable I use to determine if the user is dragging the mouse.
        {

            redlinemovedpoints = new Point(e.Location.X - redline_panstart.X,
                    e.Location.Y - redline_panstart.Y); // this is the X and Y points move

            horizontalstart = new Point(horizontalstart_initialpoint.X + redlinemovedpoints.X, horizontalstart_initialpoint.Y+redlinemovedpoints.Y);
            horizontalend = new Point(picbox_mpr.Width, horizontalend_initialpoint.Y + redlinemovedpoints.Y);
            verticalstart = new Point(verticalstart_initialpoint.X + redlinemovedpoints.X, verticalstart_initialpoint.Y + redlinemovedpoints.Y);
            verticalend = new Point(verticalstart_initialpoint.X + redlinemovedpoints.X, picbox_mpr.Height);

            picbox_mpr.Invalidate(); //re draws the lines, this time moved X or Y depending the pan.

        }

}

void picbox_mpr_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        //save the line points positions where after panning the image
        horizontalstart_initialpoint = horizontalstart;
        horizontalend_initialpoint = horizontalend;
        verticalstart_initialpoint = verticalstart;
        verticalend_initialpoint = verticalend;
     }

 private void picbox_mpr_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image tmp = (Image)img.RenderImage(0);
        e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(tmp, movingPoint);
        tmp.Dispose();
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(redline, horizontalstart, horizontalend);//Draw Horizontal line.
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(redline, verticalstart, verticalend);//Draw Horizontal line.

     }
```